# software for autoslicing a song

Tags: applications, software, music

I'm searching a program for slicing a song (MP3, wav, whatever) automatically in different patterns.

Comment: please be more explicit about the meaning of "slicing in different patterns"

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand correctly, you are trying to edit a song, perhaps for a ringtone or something ?

You could try Garageband that ships with your Mac,

Or you could try this Program, Audacity, I find it very useful.
http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Hope it helps

Karl